# Getting an Ember controller's function property from inside an Ember Handlebars template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

In an Ember Handlebars template, it is possible to access a controller's (string/boolean/number based) property by using the

- `{{someProperty}}`
- `<someHtmlTag {{bindAttr someHtmlTagAttribute="someProperty" />`

constructs.

This doesn't seem to work for function-based controller properties.

## Example

**The following works**

```
//Handlebars
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    Some property: {{someProperty}}<br/>
</script>   

//Javascript
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    someProperty: "yolo",
});
```

**The following doesn't work**

```
//Handlebars
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
    Some property: {{someProperty}}<br/>
</script>   

//Javascript
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    someProperty: function() {
        return "yolo"; },
});
```

**[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/qxy9A/7/)**

---

Using the `{{bindAttr ...}}` gives a little insight into the problem:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Attributes must be numbers, strings or booleans, not function ()  ...{
```

**How can I access function-based Ember controller properties from within a Handlebars template?**

Comment: You are looking for Computed Properties, @intuitivepixel' answer below explains how to create a basic CP, for more advanced usage check http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: This might be a browser specific issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605866/what-does-property-do-in-function-property

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just need a function to be executed when the property is accessed, then you could do something like:

```
//Javascript
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    someProperty: function() {
        // do your stuff...
        return "yolo";
    }.property()
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/intuitivepixel/2p4xR/2/)

Hope it helps