# What does .property() do? in function(){}.property()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isCompleted: function(key, value){
    var model = this.get('model');

    if (value === undefined) {
      // property being used as a getter
      return model.get('isCompleted');
    } else {
      // property being used as a setter
      model.set('isCompleted', value);
      model.save();
      return value;
    }
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

I'm working through the ToDo guide for Ember.js and I can't seem to understand how this controller works. What does the .property() mean? And how come when I remove the 'return value;' line the functionality stays the same. If someone could explain exactly what's going on here that would be great.

Link to the guide: http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/marking-a-model-as-complete-incomplete/

Comment: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: @RUJordan I still don't understand why you need .property() in this code `fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')` it still seems redundant to have both a return and a .property()

Comment: Also in this piece of code `App.SongsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  longSongCount: function() {
    var longSongs = this.filter(function(song) {
      return song.get('duration') > 30;
    });
    return longSongs.get('length');
  }.property('@each.duration')
});` You're already returning the length of longSongs so why do you need .property('@each.duration')?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In javascript the only way to do some processing when getting or setting one property is using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(person, "b", {
  get : function() { 
    return person.firstName + ' ' + person.surname; 
  },
  set : function(newValue) {
    var names = newValue.split(' '); 
    person.firsname = names[0];
    person.surname = names[1]; 
  },
  enumerable : true,
  configurable : true
});
```

But this have some disadvantages:

- Isn't cross browser
- Doesn't have binding, in other words, if `firstname` or `surname` changes, the dependent property `fullname` isn't changed.
- Calling `person.name` when `person` is undefined, make an error to be throwed
- Isn't possible to trigger observers, no without additional code and aware of the depency hierachy: `firstname` depends from `fullname`, and it can be dependency of others properties arghhh!

Due to this Ember has the concept of "property", called [computed property](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/).

It can be declared in 2 ways:

```
foo: Ember.computed(function({
  ...
}).property(dependent keys);
```

or when using (the default) `Ember.ENV.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES = true`:

```
foo: function() {
  ...
}.property(dependent keys);
```

The `property(dependent keys)`, is needed because it tell to ember what is the properies that when changed, will make the property be updated.

```
fullname: function(key, value) {
  // setter
  if (value !== undefined) {
    var names = value.split(' ');
    this.set('firstname', names[0]);
    this.set('surname', names[1]);
  }
  // always return the complete result, so nexts calls to this.get('fullname') will return the cached value  
  return this.get('firstname') + ' ' + this.get('surname');
}.property('firstname', 'surname')
```

Using this, you have the advantage of:

- when changing `firstname` or `surname` to a new value, `fullname` is changed.
- The `beforeObserves` are triggered before changing the value, and the `observes` are triggered after the value change.
- Any template referencing some property is updated
- More then one call to person.get('firstname'), will return a cached value, saving processing. You can disable this using `.property(..).volatile()`
- Avoid null or undefined errors, when accessing null objects like: `controller.get('person.dog.name')` returns `undefined`, if person or dog is undefined.

I hope it helps

Comment: Ok thank you! I'm beginning to understand this better. So how come in the example in the original question is the dependent key `'model.isCompleted'` and not just `'isCompleted'`?

Comment: The confusion is because the name is nearly the same, but refer to two different properties. `isCompleted` is dependent of `model.isCompleted`, and if we use `isCompleted: function() { ... }.property('isCompleted')`, will refer to the property itself.

Comment: re: "if `firstname` or `surname` changes, the dependent property `fullname` isn't changed" [where `fullname` refers to what you actually called `b` in the example, yes?]: this is not true, at least not now; I hope it was not true in 2013. The property's getter reevaluates the expr with each access.

Answer (score 8):

`.property()` marks the function as a **computed property** so that it can be used in templates, for example, in a consistent way. Is it a JavaScript property `foo`? Or is it a function `foo()`? Computed properties solve this issue on all platforms.

The fields and paths passed as arguments are the **dependent keys**. All computed properties in Ember are cached by default. To know when a computed property needs to be recomputed, Ember needs to know which properties and paths it depends on. In the guide's example, the `fullName` computed property depends on `firstName` and `lastName`; Ember needs to know that so it can recompute `fullName` when either of those change. (Note: You can turn off caching by using `.property().volatile()`.)

Please read the guides. All of this is documented there.

Comment: So in the template there is `<li {{bind-attr class="isCompleted:completed"}}>
              {{input type="checkbox" checked=isCompleted class="toggle"}}
              <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
            </li>` and the only reason this works is because isCompleted has a .property() at the end?

Comment: In part, yes. And the dependent keys are what allow Ember to keep it up to date.

Comment: the computed properties section of 2.16.0 does not contain anything on `.property()` though https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/object-model/computed-properties/

Comment: @DanielLizik, the `.property()` syntax hasn't been in the guides in a while.  See [version 1.12.0 of the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/object-model/computed-properties/) for the last time it was included.  The current recommended way is to use `Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() { ... })`.  The functionality is the same.